# UIPickerView issue -- selected row disappears

Tags: ios, iphone, datepicker, uipickerview, uipicker

I am facing weird problem with the UIPickerView. I have implemented UIPickerView in my project and when i scroll quickly to select value from it, the selected row disappears. Please have a look at the attached image.

Not only single picker all picker in the project have same issue. I added new date picker without binding it with the code and that too have the same issue. Please can anyone let me know what could be the issue.

**I noticed one thing, When I scroll it, the selected number animate from pricker and goes to bottom left and than disappears.**

Except this UI issue everything works fine.

[image]

Thank in advance

Comment: Can u post the code where you initialising the picker

Comment: @BalajiKondalrayal thanks for comment... As I mentioned I added new datepicker which is not bind and that still has issue. It is in the xib code has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I don't know why. But, what is the version of Xcode? Just want to know.

Comment: My xcode version is Version 6.4 and I tried in 7.1 as well same issue.